# Spritekit Detecting Sprite Overlap with Collisions off

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Currently I have a Swift/Spritekit app that drops a sprite from the sky, they have collisions off so they can fall through the floor, however I am trying to make a statement that will detect when the player sprite touches the sprite falling from the sky then deletes that child and adds a point to the score var.

---

Update: 04/29/18 2:10 CST
As of now this is what I have

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var activePlayer:SKSpriteNode! = SKSpriteNode() //Sets active character
    var bg:SKSpriteNode! = SKSpriteNode()
    var bananaCollected = 0 //Defines banana var
    var timer: Timer?
    let bananaCat : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let playerCat : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2

    func bananaDrop() { //Defines bananaDrop
        let banana = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"banana")
        //print("- Debug: [bananaDrop] successfully initiated -")
        banana.name = "banana"

        //Size of banana
        banana.xScale = 0.25
        banana.yScale = 0.25

        //Defines physics properties
        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 15)
        //let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        //physicsBody.pinned = true //Suspend in air
        physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
        physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true
        //physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
        banana.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bananaCat
        banana.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        banana.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCat

        //categoryBitMask is what the physics category of the object is
        //banana.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
        //collisionBitMask is what the physics category of objects that this cannot pass through are...multiple categories would be typed like... `cat1 | cat2`
        //banana.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
        //contactTestBitMask is what the physics category of the objects that we get alerted to upon contact
        //activePlayer.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory

        banana.physicsBody = physicsBody

        //Starting Location Defined
        var x: CGFloat = 0 //Defines X
        let y: CGFloat = 400 //Defines how high up banana drops

        let bananaDrop = GKShuffledDistribution(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 11)

        //Drop locations defined (relation to X)
        switch bananaDrop.nextInt() {
        case 1:
            x = -170
        case 2:
            x = -160
        case 3:
            x = -120
        case 4:
            x = -80
        case 5:
            x = -40
        case 6:
            x = 0
        case 7:
            x = 40
        case 8:
            x = 80
        case 9:
            x = 120
        case 10:
            x = 160
        case 11:
            x = 170
        default:
            fatalError("Case num outside range")
        }
        banana.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        //Adds banana
        self.addChild(banana)
    }
    func bDropF() { //Defintes Banana Drop Final
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            self?.timer = timer
            self?.timerTime()
        })
    }
    //Stop droping bananas
    deinit {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
    func timerTime() {
        bananaDrop()
    }
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("- Debug: Game Scene Loaded -")
        bDropF() //Calls banana drop
        if let setupBG:SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "bg") as? SKSpriteNode {
            bg = setupBG
            bg.name = "bg"
            bg.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            bg.zPosition = -1
        }
        func didBeginContact(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact){ //Banana Collect
            if let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode, let secondNode = contact.bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode {

                let object1: String = firstNode.name!
                let object2: String = secondNode.name!

                if (object1 == "player") || (object2 == "banana") {
                    print("colliding!")
                }
            }
        }
        //Player Definitions
        if let randoPlayer:SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode { //Test for Char type
            activePlayer = randoPlayer      //Char Set
            activePlayer.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true     //Set dynamic
            activePlayer.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true     //Set dynamic gravity
            activePlayer.name = "player"
            print("Player Initiated")
            print("Physics set :: Dynamic(true):AffectedByGravity(true)")
        } else {
            print("Failed to initiate player")
        }
    }
    func moveActivePlayerR() {//Right Touch Player Movements Defined
        let walkAnimation:SKAction = SKAction(named: "WalkRight")!
        let moveAction:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 0, duration: 0.5) //Move Right Side
        //let moveRight:SKAction = SKAction.group([walkAnimation, moveAction]) //Depricated
        let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("walk.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

        let finalWalkR:SKAction = SKAction.group([walkAnimation, moveAction, sound])

        activePlayer.run(finalWalkR)
    }
    func moveActivePlayerL() { //Left Touch Player Movements Defined
        let walkAnimation:SKAction = SKAction(named: "WalkLeft")!
        let moveAction:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: -100, y: 0, duration: 0.5) //Move Left Side
        //let moveRight:SKAction = SKAction.group([walkAnimation, moveAction]) //Depricated
        let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("walk.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

        let finalWalkL:SKAction = SKAction.group([moveAction, sound, walkAnimation])

        activePlayer.run(finalWalkL)
    }
    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
        print("touch \( pos.x),\(pos.y)") //Debug print
        if(pos.x > 0) { //if touched right side of screen
            print("Right touch")
            moveActivePlayerR()
        } else if (pos.x < 0) { //if touched left side of screen
            print("Left touch")
            moveActivePlayerL()
        }
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for t in touches {
            self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self))
        }
    }
}
```

However even with these categories setup it still appears that I am unable to get them to collide properly. When they touch each other there is nothing in my console indicating that they have collided. Please help!

Comment: Further to Ron's answer : collisions are not on or off - they are on or off between specific objects. So you have collision off between the falling object and the floor so that the objects can fall through the floor, but other objects COULD collide with the floor and so not go through. but collisions are different from contacts - you can still have contacts between your player sprite and the falling sprite.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to have a collisionBitMask set in order to detect contact, you just need to set the contactTestBitMask to the category of the obstacle you want to detect the collision with. You then check for the collision in the didBegin func. Ensure that you have the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` set on your scene.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate

self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

when setting up your objects

```
//categoryBitMask is what the physics category of the object is    
object.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
//collisionBitMask is what the physics category of objects that this cannot pass through are...multiple categories would be typed like... `cat1 | cat2`    
object.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
//contactTestBitMask is what the physics category of the objects that we get alerted to upon contact
object.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory
```

the didBegin func in your scene

```
func didBeginContact(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode, let secondNode = contact.bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode {

        let object1: String = firstNode.name!
        let object2: String = secondNode.name!

        if (object1 == "obstacle") || (object2 == "obstacle") {
            //run some code because these 2 have collided
        }
    }
}
```

...or...

```
func didBeginContact(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.obstacleCategory || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.obstacleCategory {
        //obstacle has hit player do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Have tried to implement the categories as you said, however they still aren't colliding the way I believe they should, really appreciate your help thus far! If you could take a look at what I have I believe I am close!